# Recommended pattern to implement global Search with multiple Objects type (Ember 2 + JSONAPI)

Tags: ember.js

I am new to Ember and I will like to implement a server side search endpoint that returns results for several models/tables in DB.

Trying to figure out what is the best practice to do this in Ember.
Server results can contain several types of objects/models, each model is already defined in ember-data.

So far I am able to retrieve the results (I can see the results in ember-inspector) but I am not able to render it properly (I only have access to first object for some reason).

Current architecture:

- rails-5 server with JSONAPI response
- ember 2.3 with multiple models

Flow:

1. POST /search with body:

   {"search":{"query": "xxx","size": "10"}}
2. RESULT:

   {
     "data": [
       {
         "id": "111111",
         "type": "foo",
         "attributes": {
           "x": "y"
         }
       },
       {
         "id": "222222",
         "type": "bar",
         "attributes": {
           "z": "y"
         }
       }
     ]
   }

Comment: What does your model hook look like? If data is pushed to ember data store but not available as routes model I guess it's an issue with your model hook.

Comment: Maybe use a SearchResult Model and a polymorphic relationship?

Comment: @Lux that is kind of I am currently trying, I can see the data in ember-inspector, but is not rendered, I only have access to firstObject

Comment: Then please show your code

Comment: and your template code ;)